# Can a wizard who studied to be an Animagus have the possibility to choose in which animal he will be transformed?

Tags: harry-potter

And what will define in which animal a wizard will be transformed? is it due to his apparence or moral quality?

Comment: oh sorry! thanks :-)

Comment: no need to be sorry. FYI: You can see possible duplicates in a dropdown when you're typing up your question.